# scanf() changes the variables before it to an ASCII value if set as "%s" after using it for "%d"

Tags: c, scanf

If I use `scanf()` for a string after defining an integer variable using the same function, all the previous variables are changed to an ASCII value of the integer itself.

For example:

```
int main(){
    int m, n;
    printf("M = ");
    scanf("%d", &m);
    
    printf("N = ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    char str[1];
    scanf("%s", &str);
    
    printf(" %d\n", m);
    printf(" %d\n", n);
    printf(" %s\n", str);
```

If I input "1", "2", and "ab", the N variable would be changed to the ascii value of the math variable, resulting in 1, 98, ab. I was expecting the function to output "1", "2", and "ab" instead.

Comment: What is `math`?

Comment: `char str[1];` can hold one character. Since strings are NUL terminated the only possible value is an empty string. Buffer overflows are undefined behavior and can affect other variables.

Comment: A- I meant str instead of math- I accidentally left that in and forgot to change it- apologies

Comment: I thought character variables count from 0? so str[0] would signify the first character, str[1] as the 2nd, etc etc.

Comment: There is no `'&'` before `str`. It is already a pointer due to array/pointer conversion (even thought it is wildly too short) Use `char str[128]`. **Lesson:** Never skimp on buffer size... (or better, use `fgets()` for all user input and `sscanf()` as needed for conversion) A single call to `printf()` is all that is needed, e.g. `printf (" %d\n %d\n %s\n", m, n, str);`

Comment: *"I thought character variables count from 0*". They do. But that's not the problem. The problem is that `char str[1];` is an array of one char. That is, the only valid index is 0. So you can't use it to store a string in `scanf` - even a single character string requires 2 bytes to store as every string has a NUL terminator.

Comment: MinhNguyen, try `char str[1]; scanf("%s", &str);` --> `char str[100]; scanf("%99s", str);`.  (larger size, width limit, no `&`).

Comment: Ohhhh, I forgot to be aware of the NUL terminator- but at the same time thought that it was already accounted for when I declare the variable.

Answer (score -1):

```
int m, n;
char str[1000];
printf("M = ");
scanf("%d", &m);

printf("N = ");
scanf("%d", &n);
```

// char str[4];
scanf("%s",&str);

```
printf(" %d\n", m);
printf(" %d\n", n);
printf(" %s\n", str);
```

I think it is because of char[1]

Comment: What is `char str[4];`?  What is `scanf("%s",&str);`?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).